# how to find all children of a parent recursively Ecto Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an Ecto Model as `LabTest.Schema`, it has

1. name
2. id
3. parent_id

I am trying to get all children of a root LabTest, such

there is a LabTest, `Microbiology` (name), it doesn't have any parent_id, but it has an id, and that Id is parent to another lab test, and those lab tests can have more lab tests children

a LabTest is

```
%LabTest.Schema{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "lab_tests">,
  id: "ca394ae8-087f-4f5b-a7a3-0f530e6ae5e2",
  name: "Adenocorticotropic Hormone (ACTH)",
  parent_id: "5bcc307c-7540-4256-a68e-553d1ed34532",
}
```

there is a hierarchical structure between all lab tests, like a tree.

```
LabTest (this has an ID)
   -> Children (This has a parent_id, and an ID)
   -> Children (This has a parent_id, and an ID)
      -> Children (This has a parent_id of above Parent children ID, and an ID)
      -> Children (This has a parent_id of above Parent children ID, and an ID)
      -> Children (This has a parent_id of above Parent children ID, and an ID)
```

I have a root LabTest Name (Microbiology): of lab tests (Which doesn't have any parent_id), and I am trying to find all its children's names,

Any help would be wonderful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using [recursive CTE](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#with_cte/3-recursive-ctes):

```
id = 1

initial_query = 
  LabTest
  |> where([c], is_nil(c.parent_id))

recursion_query =
  LabTest
  |> join(:inner, [c], ct in "cte", on: c.parent_id == ct.id and c.parent_id == ^id)

lab_test_query =
  initial_query 
  |> union_all(^recursion_query)


LabTest
|> recursive_ctes(true)
|> with_cte("cte", as: ^lab_test_query)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but how it will fetch all children of a parent? I don't see any option above to pass Top Parent

Comment: We do have a parent and we want to find children to that parent.

Comment: I mean, how we will pass the very first Parent ID or Name in the above to get all children? can you explain a bit?

Comment: you can filter it in the join query, I'll update the answer

Comment: unfortunately, it returns literally everything in the database.